# Used Content WebEditor in SharePint 2013. NO longer works in SharePoint 2019. What happened

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a file called FASUOnly.CEWP.js. I am using Content Editor to call this file and run the script to add text to a SharePoint for. This works perfectly in SharePoint 2013. We migrated from 2013 to 2016 and then 2019. This will not work in SharePoint 2016 or 2019. I have jquery working just fine on different pages throughout SharePoint so why won't it work on this one form? Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../SiteAssets/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<!-- Reference jQueryUI on the Google CDN -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Headings
        $('<tr><td><h2>DISCOVERY REQUEST</h2></td></tr>').insertBefore($('h3:contains("CaseID")').parent().parent());
        $('<tr><td><h2>---------- FOR FASU USE ONLY ----------</h2></td></tr>').insertBefore($('h3:contains("CD")').parent().parent());

        //Hide content type dropdown in Edit
       // $("select[id*='ContentTypeChoice']").closest('tr').hide();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can check the developer tool console window for errors.
2. Check whether the corresponding DOM structure has changed after the upgrade.